# Reusable Components with props of union type array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type Employees = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: any;
  phone: string;
};

type Inventories = {
  id: string;
  inventoryType: string;
};

type Items = {
   id: string;
   inventoryType: string
   itemName: string;
   description: string;
   brand: string;
};


type props = { data: (Employees | Inventories | Items)[] };
const FlexGrid = ({ data }: props) => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center" alignItems="center">
      {data.map((d, index) => {
        return (
          <Grid item key={d.id}>
            <Cards data={d} />
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  );
};

type props = { data: Employees | Inventories | Items };
const Cards = ({ data }: props) => {
  return (
    <Card >
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          alt="Mice"
          height="250"
          image={mice}
          title="Mice"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            // Display Employee | Inventory | Item "name" here
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
           // Display other properties from "data"
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            // Display other properties from "data"
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

I have this reusable component `<FlexGrid />` which receives a union type prop (should I be even be doing this?) which in return a list of `<Cards />` - What's the best way to generate `<Cards />` with dynamic details depending on the data props received?

Also what's the difference between

`type propsA = {data: type1[] | type2[]}`

and

`type propsB = {data: (type1 | type2)[]}`

a variable of type propsA wouldn't allow me to map it saying `"This expression is not callable"`

Comment: `propsA` says the array must be all `type1` or all `type2`.  `propsB` says that it can be a mix of both.